# happening segment fault when i use pthread_create

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I want to create thread to excute the task from external,
however，`pthread_create` will lead to segmentation fault but the result value is `0`.

It also fails if I set `thread_function` just with a `;` and without any other code.

```
typedef struct {
    int                socket;     
    int                login_state;  
    int                connect_state; 
    int                send_length;    
    ATW_TReqParams*    thread_aparams; 
    void (*ATWFtpNotify)(ATW_TReqParams* AParams);     
}ThreadData;

pthread_t worker_thread;
ThreadData* thread_data = NULL;

void* thread_function(void* arg) {
    if (arg == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    ThreadData* data = (ThreadData*)arg;

    while (data != NULL) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&task_mutex);

        while (data->ATWFtpNotify == NULL) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&task_condition, &task_mutex);
        }

        if (data->ATWFtpNotify != NULL) {

            data->ATWFtpNotify(data);

            data->ATWFtpNotify = NULL;
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&task_mutex);
    }
}

int ATWPlusOpen(int AChipNo)
{
    int result = 1;

    if (thread_data == NULL)
        thread_data = (ThreadData*)malloc(sizeof(ThreadData));
    if (thread_data != NULL) {
        thread_data->socket = -1;
        thread_data->login_state = 0;
        thread_data->connect_state = 0;
        thread_data->thread_aparams = NULL;
        thread_data->ATWFtpNotify = NULL;
        result = pthread_create(&worker_thread, NULL, thread_function, thread_data);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: What is `ThreadData` ? Can you update your post to provide a [MCVE]?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where exactly do you get segfault? Did you run the program in a debugger and inspect where it happens?

Comment: @Gerhardh：thank you. i compile to a .so file,  i dont know how to use gdb correctly,   here are the info:
 (gdb) run ./debug/libtest.so
Starting program: /home/wyh/FTP/AT/debug/libtest.so ./debug/libtest.so

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7ff7000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff7ff7000 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000000002 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007fffffffe2bb in ?? ()
#3  0x00007fffffffe2dd in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Comment: @Mathieu: OK, I update.  ThreadData is just a struct, which include the data  that  thread need to handle

Comment: Why are you even exposing this struct to the outside world? Why not make one struct per thread, pass it as thread argument and then only let the thread creating process touch it.

Comment: @Lundin：thank you, I want to generate a dynamic lib to outside, and  ATWPlusOpen  will be exposed. Actually, I write a  ATWPlusAddCmdList to set 
 different tasks for this thread which is also need to be exposed. So i have to create thread by this way

Answer (score 1):

One bug is that your thread callback lacks a `return` in some of the execution paths. Meaning it will likely crash each time the thread finishes. If you enable compiler warnings and pay attention to them, then this bug would have been spotted. There could be other bugs as well.